# pytest localstack test error You must specify a region

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pytest, terraform, localstack

I have knocked up a python test which spins up a localstack container and provisions an S3 bucket and a lambda inside the localstack container.

The test looks like this:

```
def my_test(self, setup_terraform_infra):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    buckets = list(s3.buckets.all())
    assert len(buckets) == 1

    lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda', region_name='us-east-1')
    payload = json.dumps(self.load_file(TEST_INPUT_SUCCESS_MESSAGE))

    list_function_resp = lambda_client.list_functions(
        MasterRegion='us-east-1',
        Marker='',
        MaxItems=123
    )

    assert len(list_function_resp['Functions']) == 1

    response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName='function',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        Payload=payload,
    )
```

Everything works in the above test until you hit the invoke function:

```
response = lambda_client.invoke(
    FunctionName='function',
    InvocationType='RequestResponse',
    Payload=payload,
)
```

This causes the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InternalFailure) when calling the Invoke operation (reached max retries: 4): Error executing Lambda function arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:function: You must specify a region.
botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.
```

If I hop onto the docker image that the tests create I can reproduce this error if I do:

```
awslocal lambda invoke --region eu-west-1 --function-name "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:function" --payload "{}" reponse.json
```

Error:

```
>>> botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.
```

I have tried setting both AWS_DEFAULT_REGION & DEFAULT_REGION in the docker image. But the issue still occurs.

I have ran out of ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had exactly the same issue before, the error message is unfortunately misleading, but my problem turned out to be due to using the wrong `InvocationType` for the Lambda.

After setting the correct `InvocationType` (in my case it should have been set to `Event` rather than `RequestResponse`), it worked correctly.

Hope this also resolves your issue.